# Cycles render out of memory and long Initializing

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, collections

I have a very complex scene where I always get out of memory while rendering. Because I want to find out what is causing the biggest problems, I have deactivated various collections.

What I do not understand, however, is that Blender even initializes almost 6 minutes during rendering, even if I have deactivated all collections. Is an object not completely deactivated with the deactivation of the collection or am I getting something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the command line to render? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

Comment: Yes that's an interesting idea that I haven't tried yet. But I would still be interested in why the problem is so and why the initialization takes so long if I deactivate all collections

Comment: This problem is pretty confusing, but this is what I think really happens: The collections are just hidden by disabling them, and they are still being processed in the render. This is the only theory that I think accurate.

Answer (score 2):

It appears, that you run out of memory cause your computer has to load the scene twice cause it has to run the viewport as well. Try rendering the scene without actually opening it.
There is an Add-On by @p2or that can do this:

https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom

Thank him!! and also check his other add-on´s!!!!